# Migrate from Google Plugin for Eclipse to Cloud Tools for Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have an application in App Engine + Java GWT with MVC architecture (Google Web Application Project). I have three sections of code - Server, Client and Shared all under one GWT project.
This was initially built using the Google Plugin for Eclipse. I now want to migrate to the new 'Cloud Tools for Eclipse'

I have already tried following the steps here :
https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe

The above was unsuccessful.

Comment: What exactly does unsuccessful mean? Any errors?